# Touchpad gets disabled right after login

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

My touchpad had been working fine till yesterday and all of a sudden started acting weird. There is no trace of touchpad in settings and as soon as I login I get a notification that says "Touchpad was disabled because a mouse was plugged in". There is no mouse plugged in.

After some digging around, I tried checking in dconf-editor but I cannot find touchpad there either. I tried

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

Nothing seems to work.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 with KDE Plasma

Please help!